# Homebrew won't link git

Tags: macos, permissions, git, homebrew

When I installed git or upgrade git via `brew` I couldn't link it with `brew link git`. If I try `sudo brew link git` I get:

> cowardly refusing to sudo brew link

It says that I have to check the permissions on:

```
/usr/local/share/gitk/lib
/usr/local/share/git-gui/lib
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates
/usr/local/share/git-core/templates/hooks
/usr/local/share/git-core
```

I `chmod`ed everything to 777 but I'm not sure if it is good.

I can now link git. Should I change the permission to something less permissive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

777 permissions aren't necessarily bad here – you'll probably never run into permissions problems, and it's not a huge security issue I'd say.

Anyway, the "normal" permissions on `/usr/local/share` that Homebrew requires should be (recursively) 755, thus `rwxr-xr-x`.

```
chmod -R 755 /usr/local/share
```

At least `brew` shouldn't need sudo permissions to ever do anything in there. Only `/usr/local` is owned by `root`, but writable for the `staff` group, in which your user should be in.

For fixing existing Homebrew installations, check out [this gist](https://gist.github.com/768518), which is a script that will attempt to correct your `/usr/local` permissions.

---

As an example, here's the directory listing of one of my (sane) Homebrew installations with `ghostscript` being the only exception that needed a `sudo brew link`:

```
aeneas:local werner$ ls -la /usr/local/share/
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  11 werner  staff  374 Mar  5 14:53 .
drwxrwxr-x  14 werner  staff  476 Feb 28 12:51 ..
drwxr-xr-x   6 werner  staff  204 Mar  5 14:54 aclocal
drwxr-xr-x   8 werner  staff  272 Mar  5 14:53 doc
lrwxr-xr-x   1 werner  staff   34 Feb  8 12:26 ffmpeg -> ../Cellar/ffmpeg/0.10/share/ffmpeg
drwxr-xr-x   4 werner  wheel  136 Apr 16  2010 ghostscript
lrwxr-xr-x   1 werner  staff   36 Mar  5 14:53 git-core -> ../Cellar/git/1.7.9.2/share/git-core
lrwxr-xr-x   1 werner  staff   35 Mar  5 14:53 git-gui -> ../Cellar/git/1.7.9.2/share/git-gui
lrwxr-xr-x   1 werner  staff   32 Mar  5 14:53 gitk -> ../Cellar/git/1.7.9.2/share/gitk
lrwxr-xr-x   1 werner  staff   34 Mar  5 14:53 gitweb -> ../Cellar/git/1.7.9.2/share/gitweb
drwxr-xr-x   9 werner  staff  306 Mar  5 14:53 man
```

Comment: For more diagnosing steps, run `brew doctor`.

Comment: Unfortunately, brew doctor does not give any useful information in this case. The mentioned gist fixed a similar problem for me, thanks :)

Comment: once I installed brew I've not needed to use sudo for much of anything.  Perhaps you sudo'd something you shouldn't have at some point which got the permissions and or ownership out of whack?

Comment: @dstarh That's usually the issue. These days Homebrew shouldn't do anything when `sudo` is used.

Comment: Why doesn't Homebrew allow us to use sudo? We keep having to mess with our permissions to link things when it should just let us `sudo brew link [package]` like apt-get does. I just copy the libraries from the cellar myself every time I want to update something rather than trying to deal with this.

Comment: @9000 I just found that whenever you start messing with `sudo`, you end up with problems later anyway. `apt-get` is different since it installs stuff system-wide. Homebrew instead runs in a directory that is not even used by default on OS X. I think they've made a sensible choice here. People can really mess up stuff when they start using `sudo` in despair.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried the gist yet, but tried to `chmod 775` on the folder. As it owned by `root:wheel` it cannot be changed. I referenced a Japanese site.

```
sudo chown yourusername:admin -R /usr/local/share/ghostscript
brew link ghostscript
brew doctor
```

then it works for me above.